# Blue Prism - Using Multiple Applications in one Process - Retaining Dependent Data

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to automate a process in blue prism where I am using multiple applications. The applications need to collect information such as email addresses, and retain them and then use that same data information on a different business object.

For example, my first business object logs onto a program to collect email addresses from users. Then a different application should be opened in a new object but I need to transfer that data across as obviously the email addresses will change every time so I don't believe I can use the environmental section.

I have worked out how to transfer data from object --> Process, but I can't get it object --> object or Process --> Object.

If anyone has any ideas or work arounds for my problem that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, You can transfer data from Object to Process, and from Process to Object. 
In the Object you just need to double click on End Stage and add an Outputs. In Process you need to specify where to store the data.

[image: End Stage]

Then you can use this outputs in process and transfer them to another Object using Inputs. To do this, you need to double click on Start Stage of your next Object and add an Inputs there. And In Process you need to specify from what variable data should be taken.

[image: Start Stage]

And you should not interact object to object. The whole data should be retain in the process layer.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, Thanks so much on your response. Could you please elaborate on transferring data from Process back to an Object?

Comment: You need to open Object in Object Studio. Double Ckick on Start Stage and add Inputs there. And create a variable in Object where you will store the data. Then in Process, double click on action that use this object and there, in inputs, you will see that you can add some data there.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I am just slightly confused how this works as I though Blue prism works by Processes being made up from the objects, so I don't understand how it can be possible for the process to then affect an object. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Actually, object is the instrument that a process uses to control an application. And it should not contain any business logic or process rules. All your processes you should make in process studio. And processes should call objects there.